# How to set Content Type for a temporary file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a rake task that fetches XML documents and saves them to a model in my app.  The task worked until I added validation of content_type to the model

The task now gives the error:

```
Datafile content type is invalid, Datafile is invalid
```

How can i set the tmp file's content_type to text/xml so that the validation passes?

The task code is below:

```
  task :fetch_documents => :environment do        
    Net::FTP.open("www.example.com", "xxxxx", "xxxxx") do |ftp|          
      ftp.nlst.each do |file_name|
        tmp = Tempfile.new(['foo', '.xml' ])
        ftp.gettextfile(file_name, tmp.path)
        # save it
        document = Document.new
        document.file_name = File.basename(file_name)
        document.datafile = tmp
        document.save!
        tmp.close
        end
     end
  end
```

Comment: this may helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621863/setting-content-type-for-mp4-files-on-s3?rq=1

Comment: @devanand thanks, but it isn't just s3, I'm just running the task locally.

Comment: @devanand  actually, that did help : )  - it led to using MIME::Types.type_for("filename.xml").first.content_type to get the content-type which was application/xml  -  adding that to the model validation got me through.  thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find out the content-type to use like this:

```
gem install mime-types
```

and added to my rake task:

```
require 'mime/types'
```

I then broke into the pry repl and used

```
MIME::Types.type_for(tmp.path).first.content_type
```

which enabled me to add the correct mime type to the model validation:

```
application/xml
```

I'm not sure why the files are application/xml when  the form uploaded files are text/xml but in hindsight, a pretty obvious fix!