# Paperclip security validation error mp4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, paperclip

I am using Paperclip to upload videos and keep getting a Security Validation error about the content type

The error when saving an mp4 to my model class is "content type discovered from file command: video/mp4. See documentation to allow this combination."

The save looks like this

```
AssignmentEventVideo.create(video: "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/dev/upload/0c857445-09ad-44b6-bbfa-810a9974a501/ScreenCaptureProject4.mp4")
```

The model class

```
class AssignmentEventVideo < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :video, :styles => {
                          :medium => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'mp4' },
                          :android => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'webm'},
                          :mobile => { :geometry => "300x300", :format => 'png', :time => 2 },
                          :thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'png', :time => 2 }
                      }

  validates_attachment_content_type :video, content_type: ['video/mp4']
end
```

If have tried disabling validation all together with the code below but it still throws the error

```
 do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :video
```

I have confirmed that the file command is return the correct type with
    file -b --mime ScreenCaptureProject3.mp4

which returns

```
video/mp4; charset=binary
```

The save is working fine for another model class that accepts images and checks content using

```
validates_attachment_content_type :photo, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

I'm not sure where to turn next - except to recreate the class and change the column name to something that doesn't clash with video?

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Seems to be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621863/setting-content-type-for-mp4-files-on-s3 Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks katafrakt - you got me on the right path.

I was using a presigned_post and uploading to S3 using JQuery FileUploader. This was not setting the Content-Type and I was getting back a binary/octet type that Paperclip didn't know how to deal with.

I set `content_type` on the presigned post, which stores the right meta data in S3 and all is well.