# AWS S3 PHP SDK presigned url restrict content type

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I am trying to make a PutObject presigned request using the AWS S3 PHP SDK.

I have gotten the request to work but now I only want to allow my users to be able to only upload video files.I have tried a lot of combinations and searched a lot but I could not get it to work.

Here is the sample code I use:

```
$cmd = $this->s3client->getCommand('PutObject', [
        'Bucket' => 'myBucket',
        'Key' => 'inputs/' . $movie->getId(),
        'ACL' => 'private',
        'Conditions' => ['Starts-With', '$Content-Type', 'video/'], // I have tried other combinations but it seems to not work
    ]);

    $request = $this->s3client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+30 minutes');

    $movie->setSignedUrl((string)$request->getUri());
```

The signed url generated does never include the Content-Type in the X-Amz-SignedHeaders query parameter, only the host is included.

Comment: Have you tried taking a look at this example? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621863/setting-content-type-for-mp4-files-on-s3

Answer (score 1):

The [`putObject()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putobject) request has no documented `Conditions` key.

You appear to be confusing S3's `PUT` upload interface with the [pre-signed `POST`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-post.html) capability, which supports policy document conditions like `['Starts-With', '$Content-Type', 'video/'],`

`PUT` does not support "starts with".  It requires the *exact* `Content-Type` and the key for this (which should result in the header appearing in the `X-Amz-SignedHeaders` query string parameter) is simply `ContentType`.  It goes in the outer parameters array, just like `Bucket` and `Key`.

But if you want to support multiple content types without knowing the specific type in advance, you need to use `POST` uploads.

Comment: Yes, I was confusing the two.
However, I have also tried using the ContentType key but it seems to be ignored.
I have submitted an issue on the GitHub repo:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/1521

Comment: Re: your issue on Github, as mentioned above, the `PUT` API itself does not support restricting to Content-Type *patterns*, like `video/*`.  It only supports the complete value, like `video/mp4`.  I disagree with the architectural decision not to sign the header, as it seems to dumb-down the code for the benefit of people who are using it incorrectly, but even if that worked as expected, it would not be useful for your purpose, for this reason.